# Error in deploying React & TypeScript to firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, web-hosting, host

I have a React and TS front-end application that I intend to deploy on firebase,
Here are the steps I followed:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`
and then I ran
`firebase init`

choose yes to the single page application, select the build file as source instead of public,

ran
`npm run deploy`
then
firebase deploy,

and now I got this error:

````
i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[wedding-hire-2]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[wedding-hire-2]: found 13 files in build
⠙  hosting: uploading new files [12/13] (92%)
Error: Task f35eef8ef07b43be8ac0a406c9f8df728d3b63a0a21059d8011fcd03ab12e2dc failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: Timeout reached making request to https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/wedding-hire-2/versions/0395a57a90f5c3d0/files/f35eef8ef07b43be8ac0a406c9f8df728d3b63a0a21059d8011fcd03ab12e2dc``` 
and here are my files in order: 

.firebaserc
```{
  "projects": {
    "default": "wedding-hire-2"
  }
}
````

firebase.json

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```